# Copying files across LAN to Windows 10 share results in "empty" files

Tags: windows, network-share, debian-jessie

Copying files across a LAN to a Windows 10 shared folder results in the correct filename and extension being created, yet the resultant files are 0KB in size.

Investigation has revealed no apparent network connectivity issues.

The files are being copied from Debian 8.6 Jessie (Mate Desktop) to a shared folder which is correctly mounted.

If I add a file to the share from Windows, it can be accessed from Debian.  If I add a file from Debian, all I see from Windows is the aforementioned 0KB file.

Can anyone shed some light, or perhaps offer some assistance with regards to investigation/diagnosis?

Comment: I've seen antivirus software cause this type of behavior. What antivirus/antiwalmare software is installed on the Windows machine?

Comment: Only the default Windows Defender application.